# second order nonhomogeneous differential equation help? (easy)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

finn the general solution to the nonhomogeneous differential equation

$$y''+ 2y'-3y = 5e^{-3x}$$

and I have to use undetermined coefficients?

ok so what I did was found out that the homogeneous equation $y''+2y'-3y$ gives me $y=C1e^x + C2e^{-3x}$

and to solve the rest I find $y_p=Ae^{-3x}, y'_p=-3Ae^{-3x}, y''_p=9Ae^{-3x}$ and then I put that into the equation respectively and that is equal to $5e^{-3x}$ then I divide the whole thing with $e^{-3x}$ so I get $9A-6A-3A=5$ so I get $0=5$?? this cant be right or can it? if its right then Idk what to do next etc :P maybe I did something wrong? well thanks for tips and solutions and help :)

Comment: I mean if I have done it right it looks like the solution should just be the general solution of the characteristic equation?

Comment: $Ae^{-3x}$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation $0=y''+2y'-3y$, so obviously can't be a solution to the nonhomogeneous equation $y''+2y'-3y=5e^{-3x}$ too, because then you'd have $0=y''+2y'-3y=5e^{-3x}\implies 0=5e^{-3x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since your complimentary has a coincident term of $e^{-3x}$, try

$$y_p(x) = a x e^{-3x}$$

So we have:

- $y_p' = ae^{-3x} - 3 a x e^{-3x}$
- $y''_p = a(-6 e^{-3x} + 9xe^{-3x})$

Now, substitute those in the ODE and equate terms to solve for $a$.

See this [*web page*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx) and the table for when this condition happens and the approaches to resolve it.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but im not sure how to handle the A when taking the product rule of that? :P, do I just get A's in every single expression?

Comment: y'p dont have any x, is that right or?

Comment: well I tried and everything with x in it went out so I got -6A+2A=5 --> A = 5/4 :DD?

Comment: ahh yeah of course :P but if u had same equation and its equal to x^2 * e^x +3xe^x what do you think y_p is? :)